# Running IPv4 program in IPv6 network

Tags: ipv6, ipv4

I have an IPv4 windows client program and IPv4 Linux server. What I need is to run them in pure IPv6 network, although machines have dual stack.

At the beginning I thought it's not a problem: I'll use 4in6 protocol ([rfc2473](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2473)) and that's all.
I found a simple guide for Linux configuration [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Linux+IPv6-HOWTO/chapter-configuring-ipv4-in-ipv6-tunnels.html), but when I started to configuring windows 7, I couldn't find how to do it. There are plenty of info on how to tunnel IPv6 over IPv4 (6in4, Teredo) but not an opposite.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be ahead of the curve on this.  Most of the world is having to use tunnels to get IPV6 connectivity.

I would try using a standard IPv4 VPN over IPv6.  L2TP should be easy to setup.  If you know the ports involved and they are all TCP, you might get away with using an SSH tunnel which should be even easier to setup.  OpenVPN should run with IPv6 as the transport level between endpoints, but I haven't tried it.